# How to efficiently insert multiple rows at the start of a ListView?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a ListView and a collection of ListViewItem. I simply want to insert all items in the collection at the top of the ListView.

Currently, I am doing it this way:

```vb
CollectionOfListViewItems.Sort(New CustomComparer(SortOrder.Descending))
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In CollectionOfListViewItems
    TargetListView.Items.Insert(0, lvi)
Next
```

Since every insert operation will shift all items in the ListView, each insert operation will take O(n) time which seems like a bit of a waste.

Is there a better way of going about the same? Note that I know about [`InsertRange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insertrange?view=netcore-3.1) but unfortunately, that method is not available for the collection `ListView.Items`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you're appending or inserting items, whenever you're making a large change to the ListView, you should always call `BeginUpdate()` before making the changes and then `EndUpdate()` after. This will prevent the ListView from visually updating its items (which is the part that takes the most time).

Your code should look something like this:

```
TargetListView.BeginUpdate()

For Each lvi As ListViewItem In CollectionOfListViewItems
    TargetListView.Items.Insert(0, lvi)
Next

TargetListView.EndUpdate()
```

---

### References:

- [`ListView.BeginUpdate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate):

  > Prevents the control from drawing until the [`EndUpdate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.endupdate) method is called.

Comment: Oh whoops I meant `InsertRange()` instead of `AddRange()`...

Comment: @Burhan Ah okay. Well, the answer remains the same anyway. Using `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` should cut down the time required for executing the loop significantly.