# Create object in for-each loop, VB

Tags: vb.net, loops, object, foreach

I'm looping through a collection. In the loop I've got a simple if-statement and depending on the if-statement I'm creating a new object which i'm adding to a ListBox (as ItemCollection).

This works fine but seems to be very inefficient since it's very slow even though I'm not looping through to many rows. Any tips on how to make this more efficient, or isn't there any way to do it?

Is it concidered bad practice to create an object within a loop?

I hope this code-snipping will be enough to get an understandning.

```
   For Each i In vm.PersonCollection
         If vm.FilterListView(i) Then          
                ListBoxContainer.Items.Add(New PersonSyncEntityUserControl With {.DataContext = i})
         End If
   Next
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64468567/8967612

Comment: I would suggest that a better option than calling `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` is to create all the items first and then call `AddRange`: `ListBoxContainer.Items.AddRange(vm.PersonCollection.Where(Function(i) vm.FilterListView(i)).Select(Function(i) New PersonSyncEntityUserControl With {.DataContext = i}).ToArray())`. That said, if `FilterListView` is making changes to a `ListView` then that's a further issue so you would need to call `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` for that, if you can't find a way to make that check more efficient.